# How to have socket information auto add to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to have my twitter socket automatically add information to MySQL database after I start the socket. But nothing is being added to the DB. The twitter information is being emitted, but MySQL is not collecting...
The console.logs all print. However, I'm getting consistent Error for no default field.

```
{ [Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'keyword' doesn't have a default value]
code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
errno: 1364,
sqlState: 'HY000',
index: 0 }
```

Here is MySQL table:

| id            int(11)    NO    PRI  NULL              |auto_increment
| keyword       char(25)   NO    MUL  NULL                                          |
| screenName    char(30)   NO         NULL                                          |
| numFollowers  int(8)     NO         0                                             |
| location      char(20)   YES        NULL                                          |
| count         int(6)     NO         1                                             |
| firstDate     timestamp  NO         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                             |
| lastDate      timestamp  NO         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

---

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/twittersearch', (req, res) => {
var myNewWord = req.body.searchTerm;
myNewWord = myNewWord.toString();
// console.log(req.body.searchTerm);

// tell the twitter stream to track tweets by keyword
twitterStream1.track(myNewWord);

// check for client connections
socketServer.on('connection', (socket, err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error starting socket ", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Started socket");
    }
    // check for tweet events and send the tweet to the clients
    twitterStream1.on('tweet', (tweetData) => {
        if (tweetData.lang == 'en') {
            var logit = true;
            if (tweetData.text) {
                socket.emit('key1', tweetData);
                // console.log('emitting socket data!!!!!!');
                var keyword = myNewWord;

                var screenName = tweetData.user.screen_name;
                var numFollowers = tweetData.user.followers_count;
                var location = tweetData.user.location;
                // MySQL Command: 
                var query = 'INSERT INTO twitterInfo SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' +
                    'numFollowers = VALUES(numFollowers), count = count + 1, lastDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
                var insertObj = { screenName: screenName, numFollowers: numFollowers, location: location };
                connection.query(query, insertObj, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('MySQL Data: ' + result);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                var keyword = '??? ' + tweetData.text;
                logit = false;
            }
        }
        if (logit)
            console.log(keyword + ': ' + screenName + ' - ' + numFollowers + ' - ' + location);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: No console logs at all?

Comment: @ibu there is one. i added to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is incorrect. You can check the syntax for an insert update on [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Example query:

```
INSERT INTO twitterInfo (screenName,numFollowers,location) 
VALUES (?,?,? )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1 ;
```

With your code:

```
var query = 'INSERT INTO twitterInfo (screenName,numFollowers,location) '+
    'VALUES (?,?,? ) '+
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1 ';

var insertObj = [screenName, numFollowers,location];
connection.query(query, insertObj, function(err, result)  {...});
```

Comment: On duplicate key I want to update the "keyword" count column, not the number of followers.

Comment: OK, just switch to count rather then followers. See update

Comment: Do i just direct replace my query code? Do you concatenate the 3 lines you wrote or use commas?